# SSRS Subscriptions don't work for AD groups but do work for individual users

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

A user created email subscription fails with the "permissions granted to user domain\name are insufficient"

The user is a member of an AD group that has "Browser" and "Manage Subscriptions" role.  This person *can* browse and *can* create and manage subscriptions however the report subscription fails to email.

If I give the specific user the same roles then the subscription will work - but I don't want to have to explicitly grant individual users.

Seems like the group rights are respected interactively but are not when a scheduled subscription is being executed.  Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Can you check the error in the report server logs on the report server itself?

Comment: Is this native mode or sharepoint integrated?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding Subscriptions are executed under a user context (the user who created the subscription unless you go through an unacceptably large amount of work to change the subscription owner). So if the user who created the subscription does not have access to the resources in question I imagine the subscription will fail.

Comment: The subscription runs if the user is granted the role.  It doesn't run if an AD group is granted the role.  Problem seems to be inheriting the 'export' function from a group.